# How to properly link Visual Studio project with OpenCV (superpack) using CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cmake

I am currently digitizing old VHS cassettes. For post-processing, I would like to implement a custom algorithm with C++ & OpenCV. I have already implemented a promising prototype in Matlab, but it can only process single images (reading / writing video files is not possible in my version (R2010a); also, Matlab is far too slow).

Sadly, I am - over and over again - stuck with CMake. Though I wonder ... this can't be so difficult. I have *often* had problems with CMake, so I will go into a lot of detail here. I hope that you can not only point out to me what I am doing wrong here, but give general advices towards my usage of CMake as well. Maybe I am doing it all wrong, I don't know.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. I have downloaded the **OpenCV 2.3.1 superpack** from sourceforge. The superpack contains OpenCV source code, includes and - most importantly - the .lib and .dll files for all major platforms. For this reason, I need not build OpenCV myself. It is already done. I need only use/link it.
2. I installed (i.e. extracted to) the superpack in `C:\dev\vs2010sp1_win32\opencv\2.3.1`.
3. I have renamed `C:\dev\vs2010sp1_win32\opencv\2.3.1\OpenCVConfig.cmake.in` to `OpenCVConfig.cmake`.
4. I have created a folder for my project `C:\dev\VhsDejitterizer` with the following structure:

```
VhsDejitterizer/
    CMakeLists.txt (A)
    src/
        CMakeLists.txt (B)
        libvhsdejitter/
            CMakeLists.txt (C)
            vhsdejitter/
                util.h
                util.cpp
        main/
            CMakeLists.txt (D)
            main.cpp
```

---

Here are the contents of the individual CMakeLists.txt files.

**/CMakeLists.txt (A)**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT("VhsDejitterizer")

CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0015 OLD)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED
            NO_MODULE
            PATHS "C:/dev/vs2010sp1_win32/opencv/2.3.1"
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
```

**/src/CMakeLists.txt (B)**

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("libvhsdejitter")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("main")
```

**/src/libvhsdejitter/CMakeLists.txt (C)**

```
UNSET(source_files)
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE source_files "*.h" "*.cpp")

ADD_LIBRARY(libvhsdejitter STATIC ${source_files})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libvhsdejitter ${OpenCV_LIBS})

UNSET(source_files)
```

**/src/main/CMakeLists.txt (D)**

```
UNSET(source_files)
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE source_files "*.h" "*.cpp")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main ${source_files})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main libvhsdejitter ${OpenCV_LIBS})

UNSET(source_files)
```

---

Configuring and generating the Visual Studio .sln (...) files works well. In fact, I am not getting a single warning or error:

```
Configuring done
Generating done
```

However, my attempt to build the 'main' project in Visual Studio fails:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 04.04.2012 14:38:47.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "main.dir\Debug\main.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>CustomBuild:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '@CMAKE_LIB_DIRS_CONFIGCMAKE@/libopencv_gpu.so.@OPENCV_VERSION@@OPENCV_DLLVERSION@@OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX@.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.59
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

Further details:

- Operating system: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- IDE: Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- CMake version: 2.8.4
- Target platform (i.e. what am I compiling/building for): Windows 32-bit

---

My questions:

1. How do I successfully build the 'main' project? I.e. how to fix that error?
2. What are these `@VARIABLE_OR_SOMETHING@`? I have tried to find out where they come from, and they seem to be set up in `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. But how are they supposed to work? Are they supposed to be evaluated by Visual Studio at "build-time"? If so, how are they evaluated?
3. You have probably noticed that I have set up quite a sophisticated folder structure. Do you have any advice on this? How do you organize your libraries and projects? Are there best-practices? Where are they documented?

Thank you and best regards, Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it now. I think I can safely say that the whole mess was not my fault. Sorry for answering my own question.

---

Here is what I tried first (of course, this did *not* work for me, but it might work for others):

As Martin Foot pointed out in his answer, the *.in files are templates which are supposed to be filled out with proper values during a CMake configuration. However, I am using the OpenCV superpack, which includes all the binaries. For this reason I have, at no point, performed such a configuration step, because I assumed this would only be necessary if you wanted to compile something.

However, it seems that - even if you're using the superpack with prebuilt binaries - you have to configure the project in order to get your OpenCVConfig.cmake generated. Vadim Pisarevsky [has stated that in the OpenCV bug tracker](http://code.opencv.org/issues/597).

For some reason, this didn't work for me. I started up the Cmake GUI as usual, pointed it to the OpenCV directory and hit "Configure". I even hit "Generate" out of desperation. Yet, no OpenCVConfig.cmake appeared.

So I had to go on further ...

---

This is what actually helped:

In a recently filed bugreport related to OpenCVConfig.cmake, [Sergiu Dotenco pointed out](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1347) "that the currently provided OpenCVConfig.cmake is pretty fragile" etc. etc. Fortunately, Sergio has also provided [a custom FindOpenCV.cmake script](https://bitbucket.org/sergiu/opencv-cmake). By using his script I have finally been able to generate a working Visual Studio solution.

By the way, this is my current top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT("VhsDejitterizer")

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

SET(OPENCV_ROOT_DIR "C:/dev/vs2010sp1_win32/opencv/2.3.1")
#SET(OPENCV_USE_GPU_LIBS ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
```

I have installed Sergio's `FindOpenCV.cmake` script in a new `cmake-modules/` subfolder of the project. It is also important to note that I am using (as opposed to my original setup, where I used the *"config mode"*) the minimal FIND_PACKAGE variant (*"module mode"*). Only if the minimal variant is used, CMake is looking for `Find<package-name>.cmake` scripts in the CMake module path. See the [CMake documentation for FIND_PACKAGE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afind_package).

---

I have also found this guide, which is about how to properly use CMake if you're a library developer: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file

Comment: Best to accept your answer if you fix your own problem as it will let other people know what to do in the same situation in the future :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Yet, for accepting my own answer I have to wait 2 days. That's a stackoverflow limitation.

Answer (score 1):

These variables are probably related to CMake's [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aconfigure_file) command, which allows you to specify a parameterised template document (typically with the extension ending in `.in`) and you can substitute CMake variables into the file to create it. They are evaluated at the time of the `configure_file` call, which happens when running CMake. I think what's happening is that there will be a parent CMake script to the one that you've taken which will configure that file with the contents of those variables and then use it in an `add_subdirectory` call. I would suggest checking for any readme that describes the top level run process (or any file which defines those variables then substitute them manually).

Comment: Okay, I have found an official guide for [OpenCV & CMake](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake). I have installed the provided FindOpenCV.cmake and adapted my top-level CMakeLists.txt to make use of it. I specify the path to OpenCV by setting OpenCV_DIR before calling FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED). With this setup, it actually finds OpenCV and configures a lot of CMake variables related to libraries, include directories etc. However, it fails at parsing opencv/2.3.1/include/opencv/cvver.h, because that file does not exist. Obviously, the provided FindOpenCV.cmake is outdated.

Comment: Okay. The above parsing error of cvver.h happens **iff** there is no OpenCVConfig.cmake. (I had temporarily deleted that file after reading your post, because I have never executed any configure command, but instead simply renamed the .in file.)

Comment: Now I'm getting the same error as in my original setup. The only difference is that several CMake cache variables related to OpenCV show up in the CMake GUI. (This is not the case with my original setup, for reasons which are unknown to me. It might be due to a misunderstanding of the NO_MODULE flag/mode.) On a sidenote: Most of the OpenCV variables are set to "...-NOTFOUND", even though "OpenCV_FOUND" itself is marked as "true".

Answer (score 0):

*I have fixed it now. I think I can safely say that the whole mess was not my fault. Sorry for answering my own question.*

You fixed it?
I am having the same problem, and I followed your solution but it did not work.
When CMake executed the command 
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )

It would output:

```
One or more OpenCV components were not found:
  calib3d
  contrib
  core
  features2d
  flann
  highgui
  imgproc
  legacy
  ml
  objdetect
  video
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find OpenCV (missing: OPENCV_CALIB3D_LIBRARY
  OPENCV_CONTRIB_LIBRARY OPENCV_CORE_LIBRARY OPENCV_FEATURES2D_LIBRARY
  OPENCV_FLANN_LIBRARY OPENCV_HIGHGUI_LIBRARY OPENCV_IMGPROC_LIBRARY
  OPENCV_LEGACY_LIBRARY OPENCV_ML_LIBRARY OPENCV_OBJDETECT_LIBRARY
  OPENCV_VIDEO_LIBRARY) (found version "2.3.1")
```

Finally, I used the commands
include_directories
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES
to include all necessary directories or files, and it works, in a awkward way!